# Removes several sets of datacolumns from datatable?

Tags: c#, datatable

I'm bulk-uploading an Excel file with 470 columns to a datatable. Due to MSSQL's row size limit of 8060 bytes, I will need to delete many datacolumns. I cannot pick-and-choose what Excel files I can upload.

These are the datacolumns that I need to delete: cols [180-195], [220-245], [320-380], [430-465].

I understand that I can loop and delete the first batch (cols 180-195) using the exact column number. For the 2nd, 3rd, 4th batch, is there another way besides having to subtract the total I've deleted to the col num I'm about to delete and avoid the out-of-index exception?

In this case, when I get to the 4th batch (430-465) instead of deleting cols 430-465, I believe I will be deleting columns 330-365 (15+25+60 previous deletes)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop, start with the last column and move towards the first one. This way you can refer to original column numbers and you don't have to deal with shifts which would take place if you delete columns in the middle.